# unable to add hidden field in chosen jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

i want to add a hidden or default  field in jquery chosen for this i do

`<option value="ca.Case_Id" disabled></option>`

but don't know how to get this value . i just want this value every time however user select nothing from chosen .To solve this i try

```
var $hiddenInput = $('<input/>',{type:'hidden',id:ca.Case_Id,value:case_Id});
    $hiddenInput.appendTo('.#builderList');
```

but this also wont help. please help

Comment: I don't understand... You have a `select` in your page and you want a default value if nothing is selected in this select?

Comment: It's totally unclear, you've shown a HTML featuring the SELECT's `<option>` element, than suddenly you talk about some danymic `<input>` generation....

Comment: i'm working on a query builder in that in chosen i gave the name of the field that he want to show as out put but every time caseId is a important field so i just want if user want to see any field he can see  caseId by default

Answer (score 0):

Use either `class` selector - `appendTo('.builderList')`
OR `id` selector - `appendTo('#builderList')`

```
$('<input>', {
   type:'hidden',
   id:ca.Case_Id,
   value:case_Id
}).appendTo('#builderList'); // ID Selector
```

Comment: where i need to write this mean in ready function or some where else and how can i get this field id